# View Selected but in UV Editor?

Tags: uv

Imported a model but the uvs are too big and way far off. Is there a way to like focus on the [image]uv map? right now its all grey in the uv editor.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: Ok i added an image.

Comment: so the uv is like not in uv0 space?????? sorry but i find it hard to explain this. the uv is like not where the cursor/uv grid is at????

Comment: what im trying to do is to bring the uv back to the uv grid?

Comment: kinda like the view selected option in object mode

Comment: Select a face on the object, then move the mouse over to to the UV editor and press the Home key.

Comment: That works! Tks

Comment: Hmm, the Home key brings the view back to the uv grid but not to uv island.

Comment: then use numpad 0

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the view on the UV window has been moved or zoomed to a point where there is nothing.

Select a face on the object in the 3D viewport

Then move the mouse over to to the UV editor and press <kbd>numpad</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to center the window on the selected object.

Or press the <kbd>Home</kbd> Key to reset the view on the window.